# Docker: Output shown at http://192.168.99.100:8000/ instead of http://0.0.0.0:8000/

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hi just fount out that the "hello world" is printed out at `http://192.168.99.100:8000/` not `http://0.0.0.0:8000/` or `local:8000`.

Although the it's listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1) . I'm wondering why this is happening. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Terminal output:

```
[2016-09-19 03:56:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2016-09-19 03:56:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2016-09-19 03:56:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-09-19 03:56:50 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
192.168.99.1 - - [19/Sep/2016:04:08:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Kitematic/0.9.5 Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Electron/0.35.4 Safari/537.36"
192.168.99.1 - - [19/Sep/2016:04:08:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Kitematic/0.9.5 Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Electron/0.35.4 Safari/537.36"
192.168.99.1 - - [19/Sep/2016:04:08:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Kitematic/0.9.5 Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Electron/0.35.4 Safari/537.36"

192.168.99.1 - - [19/Sep/2016:04:08:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Kitematic/0.9.5 Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Electron/0.35.4 Safari/537.36"
[2016-09-19 04:09:14 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2016-09-19 04:09:14 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2016-09-19 04:09:14 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-09-19 04:09:14 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
192.168.99.1 - - [19/Sep/2016:04:09:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.27 Safari/537.36"
192.168.99.1 - - [19/Sep/2016:04:09:31 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "http://192.168.99.100:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.27 Safari/537.36"
[2016-09-19 04:10:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2016-09-19 04:10:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2016-09-19 04:10:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-09-19 04:10:27 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2016-09-19 04:13:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2016-09-19 04:13:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2016-09-19 04:13:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-09-19 04:13:47 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
192.168.99.1 - - [19/Sep/2016:04:13:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.27 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: "Listening at: http://0.0.0.0" means "Listening on every local address/hostname" see [this SO Question](http://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1) for details

Comment: Thanks PeterT! I understand now but why then local:8000 or 0.0.0.0:8000 cannot be shown? and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using docker-machine, given the IP your ports are exposed to, which means that all the docker-ports are exposed on the results of `docker-machine ip`. This is because all the containers are running inside of a virtual machine that docker-machine uses (probably in VirtualBox as a VM provider).

If you want to expose this port to `0.0.0.0` or localhost you need make sure you are forwarding the ports in your VirtualBox VM for whatever your docker-machine is. This requires adding the ports under the VM network settings.

Comment: Hi enderland, thanks for the comment! I understood this but how exactly can I fix this? Could you give me the procedure? I tried to google it but cannot really find the answer yet..